# TCP send command and wait for output

Tags: tcp, delphi-7, telnet, indy

I have the following situation:

```
function Mach3Code(Str: String): String;
 var StrOut: String;
 begin
   StrOut := '';

   try
     IdTelnet1.Connect();
     IdTelnet1.Write(Str);

     StrOut := ''; // assign here return output;

   finally
     IdTelnet1.Disconnect;
   end;

   Result := StrOut;

 end;
```

On the line "StrOut := '';" I need to get the text output of the server (which is a tcp server, written in vc 2008 by me as Mach3 plugin).

Normally, the client sends "COMMAND1" and the server replies with "ANSWER1#" or something like this. I need the code to wait for the answer and then return it, synchronously, so I can do something like:

```
StrResult := Mach3Code('G0X300Y200');
```

and read what the server part has sent to me.

any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know about Delphi and it's objects, but an object having a `Write` method should reasonably have a `Read` method as well.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but do you have to connect/disconnect every time? If you are calling this function often, it will be a lot of overhead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yes, it does have read method, but it does not work as expected. it just hangs. connect / disconnect is not a problem, it's rarely called.

    StrOut := IdTelnet1.ReadLn('#') 

This one waits forever ...

Comment: By default, all network sockets are blocking, which means operations such as `read` will block until there is data to read. Are you sure the server is sending a response?

Comment: Server is sending response, because it's working as expected, with putty telnet connection. the problem is within delphi app.

Comment: You may try the Overbyte ICS free library, and you will find in the examples, a script demo which answer you question.

Comment: There are 74 examples ... which one you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIdTelnet` is an asynchronous componnt, it is not suited for what you are attempting to do.  Unless you are dealing with the actual Telnet protocol, then you should use `TIdTCPClient` instead:

```
function Mach3Code(const Str: String): String;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Connect();
    IdTCPClient1.WriteLn(Str);
    StrOut := IdTCPClient1.ReadLn('#');    
  finally
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is the first thing I've tried. However, the result was the same - waiting forever. Afterwards I've tried with TIdTelnet.

Comment: Waiting forever means either the server is not sending what you are expecting, or you are not reading it correctly in the first place. Please show a full example of what the server expects you to sen and what the server is actually sending back.

Comment: I have implemented it exactly like this but in a thread and it works!

Answer (score 0):

to receive data assign an event handler of type TIdTelnetDataAvailEvent to the OnDataAvailable property of idtelnet1, i know this is not synchronous but i would re factor your code to work this way as this is how the telnet client is designed to work.

Failing that create your own TIdTCPClientCustom decendant and implement your own read thread with the relevent methods.

Comment: Maybe you're right. I will try to redo my code asynchronously in threads. The thing is that my app calls the functions and the idea is to wait for output, then continue forward depending on this output. The problem is that the output might take some time to return ( second or ten, so the interface is unresponsive during this time ... )